# Pass Parent Resource Id Down to Child Resource in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

So I've been stuck on this for hours.  I have an app with a has-many through association and I am am trying to pass down the `id` of the parent resource to the child.  Routing does work, I can browse around and even create new objects, but by url isn't showing the id in the path.

**Expected & Desired Result**

```
http://127.0.0.1:3000/locations/1/groups/1/products/1
```

**Current Result**

```
http://127.0.0.1:3000/locations/location/groups/group/products/1
```

**routes.rb**

```
...
resources :locations do
 resources :groups do
  resources :products
 end
end
...
```

**products_controller.rb**
*All my controllers are setup similar to this one.*

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_product, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @locations = Location.all
    @products = Product.all
    @groups = Group.all
  end

  def show
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @product = Product.new
  end

  def edit
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @product = Product.new(product_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.save
        format.html { redirect_to location_group_products_path(@product), notice: 'Product was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @product }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.update(product_params)
        format.html { redirect_to location_group_product_path(@product), notice: 'Product was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @product }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @product.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to location_group_products_path(@product), notice: 'Product was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private

    def set_product
      @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    end

    def product_params
      params.require(:product).permit(:name, :location_id, :group_id, :product_id)
    end
end
```

**products.html.rb**

```
<h1>Products</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @products.each do |product| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= product.name %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', location_group_product_path(:location, :group, product) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_location_group_product_path(:location, :group, product.id) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', location_group_product_path(:location, :group, product.id), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<%= link_to 'New Product', new_location_group_product_path %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the ids(or the objects) of location and the group not just their symbols. Something like this:

```
location_group_product_path(product.group.location, product.group, product)
edit_location_group_product_path(product.group.location, product.group, product)
```

Comment: Thank you.  I need to pass the location id first and in your example the first path is backwards.  I tried it though and am receiving a 
`undefined method group for #<Product:0x007fdcb7b1a9e0>` error.